# Desinstalar Java 9

Tags: java, linux, java-9

Quiero desinstalar todo aquello relacionado a java 9 en linux,para poder instalar Oracle Java 1.8.

Al ingresar `java -version` obtengo: "`-bash: /usr/bin/java: No existe el archivo o el directorio"`.
Pero al hacer `javac -version` obtengo `"javac 9.0.1"`.

A que se debe? Será que aun no se ha desinstalado el paquete de java por completo? Como logro borrar todo?

Comment: Ya intentaste con: https://www.java.com/es/download/help/linux_uninstall.xml  ?

Comment: Depende de la distribución que uses, ya que los directorios cambian y, en algunos casos, hay herramientas que automatizan el proceso. La pregunta es, entonces, demasiado amplia

Comment: Si Angel, pero no encuentro ocurrencia alguna de Java en ninguna ruta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes instalar java 8 sin que entre en conflicto, lo que debes hacer es colocar java 8 como defecto

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Estos comandos determinan con que versión específica de java quieres trabajar

Si estas usando una distro basada en Ubuntu puedes adicionar el repositorio de webupd8

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```